# I have a LEGO instruction book with the front identifying page missing. I am trying to work out which set it is. Yellow and black sea plane and boat

Tags: set-identification, creator

The LEGO set looks like a Creator set, mainly yellow bricks with many different small builds. Biplane, Speed boat, submarine, vehicle ferry, yacht, oil tanker. The photo of page 3 is attached.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

These instructions are from [4505-1: Sea Machines](http://brickset.com/sets/4505-1/Sea-Machines)

[image: picture]

- [Complete instructions book  (PDF)](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/4245377.pdf)